# Convert int and biging for filter ListViewModel C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I created a ListViewModel something like this

```
public class ListPersonalsViewModel
{
    public long PersonalID { get; set; }
    public int NationalCode { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and I use this code

```
public List<ListPersonalsViewModel> GetNamePersonal(string filter = "")
{
    if (filter == null)
    {
        return db.tblPersonals.Select(p => new ListPersonalsViewModel()
                    {
                        NationalCode = p.NationalCode,
                        PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                        FirstName = p.FirstName,
                        LastName = p.LastName
                    }).ToList();
    }

    return db.tblPersonals.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(filter)||
                                      p.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
                                      p.NationalCode.Contains(filter) ||
                                      p.PersonalID.Contains(filter))
                          .Select(p => new ListPersonalsViewModel()
                                           {
                                               NationalCode = p.NationalCode,
                                               PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                                               FirstName = p.FirstName,
                                               LastName = p.LastName
                                           }).ToList();
}
```

Now my question: **how i can convert `PersonalID` and `NationalCode` to string for work here?**

Here just 2 my string filter work

i receive this 2 error

Error   CS1929  'long' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.

Error   CS1929  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.

i think this is better for understanding

Comment: I think you are using the wrong name for the property of "ListPersonalsViewModel" class.

Comment: i know this is just some name i think u mean i most change name to ( PersonalListViewModel )

Comment: try to change "FirstName" to "FirstNameID" inside Linq Query.

Comment: Your mistake is one step earlier. You typically don't want to let ID values be visible in any user interface. They're meaningless. People should be looked up by their names and `NationalCode` indirectly by the entity the code refers to.

Comment: @GertArnold 
my friend in this case people most now his Personal ID, if they need any info they most say to operator his personal id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this code my problem solved

,,,

```
return db.tblPersonals.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(filter)||
                                  p.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
                                  p.NationalCode.ToString().Contains(filter) ||
                                  p.PersonalID.ToString().Contains(filter))
                      .Select(p => new ListPersonalsViewModel()
```

,,,

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Property name from `FirstName` to `FirstNameID` and added a comma at the end of the statement.

The main problem is with `FirstNameID = p.FirstName` this line, a "comma" was missing at end of the statement.

another Problem is, Property Name is not correct. change "Filename" with "FileNameID".

```
public List<ListPersonalsViewModel> GetNamePersonal(string filter = "")
        {
            if (filter == null)
            {
                return db.tblPersonals.Select(p => new ListPersonalsViewModel()
                {
                    NationalCode = p.NationalCode,
                    PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                    FirstNameID = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName
                }).ToList();
            }

            return db.tblPersonals.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(filter) ||
                                              p.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
                                              p.NationalCode.Contains(filter) ||
                                              p.PersonalID.Contains(filter))
                                  .Select(p => new ListPersonalsViewModel()
                                  {
                                      NationalCode = p.NationalCode,
                                      PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                                      FirstNameID = p.FirstName,
                                      LastName = p.LastName
                                  }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: my friend i have no problem with ( , )

i want know how i can convert PersonalID (bigint) and NationalCode (int) to string here